# Flash events execution order

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

Check out the next code, tell me what do you expect to be printed. Then run it and check what is really happen.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class TestFlashEvents extends Sprite
    {
        private static const DUMMY_EVENT:String = "DummyEvent";
        private var dummyObjects:Vector.<DummyObject> = new Vector.<DummyObject>(100);
        public function TestFlashEvents()
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < dummyObjects.length; i++){
                dummyObjects[i] = new DummyObject(this);
                addEventListener(DUMMY_EVENT, dummyObjects[i].listener);
            }
            removeEventListener(DUMMY_EVENT, dummyObjects[41].listener);
            dispatchEvent(new Event(DUMMY_EVENT));
        }

        private var counter:int = 0;
        public function onGettingEvent(dummyObject:DummyObject):void{
            if(counter == 25){
                for(var i:int = 0; i < 50; i++){
                    removeEventListener(DUMMY_EVENT, dummyObjects[i].listener);
                    trace("Removing", dummyObjects[i].id);
                }
            }
            trace("Handeling event", counter, dummyObject.id);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
import flash.events.Event;

class DummyObject
{
    private static var dummyObjectsCounter:int = 0;

    public var id:String;
    private var tester:TestFlashEvents;

    public function DummyObject(tester:TestFlashEvents)
    {
        this.tester = tester;
        id = "DummyObject " + dummyObjectsCounter;
        dummyObjectsCounter++;
    }

    public function listener(event:Event):void{
        tester.onGettingEvent(this);
    }
}
```

The `removeEventListener` function is actually not working. Tell me what do you think about it. I also open a bug in [adobe](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3372945).

Comment: -1 for the sensationalist title: this almost certainly isn't a bug.

Comment: @JcFx changed it. Next time you can edit it by your self. I do believe this is bug

Comment: Fair enough. -1 Removed.

Comment: basically you didn't ask a question. Stackoverflow is a Q&A forum. Please ask something, if you want answers. If you ask, how to make it right, the simplest solution is to add a boolean: needToListen, and check it in every eventlistener. Its not a bug. Its called event queue. If you dispatch an event, it will create instances, and then call the listeners. its a software architectural model, followed by not only Adobe and AS3, but also .net

Answer (score 2):

This code means Adobe caches event listener list prior to actually calling event listeners. It is an unusual behavior to have two listeners for one particular event over one single object, but if it happens, Adobe assumed that all listeners should be invoked prior to actually modifying this list. I was actually expecting all 99 listeners to get called. So, this behavior can even be by design, because re-rendering the event listener list while processing a single event will put a too heavy load on Flash, so that the lags will galore. No one wants lags.

Comment: not exactly cache.. but if an event is thrown, it will get into the event execution queue. when you remove the eventlistener, events will be in the queue. Its not a bug. Its the logical way.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be fixed by prioritizing you event listeners.
This is not a Flash bug, it is, like Vesper said caching of event listeners to prevent lag.

Here is the updated version of your code, mark the prioritizing on the `addEventListener` call.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class TestFlashEvents extends Sprite
    {
        private var _this = this;
        private static const DUMMY_EVENT:String = "DummyEvent";
        private var dummyObjects:Vector.<DummyObject> = new Vector.<DummyObject>(100);
        public function TestFlashEvents()
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < dummyObjects.length; i++)
            {
                dummyObjects[i] = new DummyObject(this);
                addEventListener(DUMMY_EVENT, dummyObjects[i].listener, false, dummyObjects.length - i);
            }
            removeEventListener(DUMMY_EVENT, dummyObjects[41].listener);
            dispatchEvent(new Event(DUMMY_EVENT));
        }

        private var counter:int = 0;
        public function onGettingEvent(dummyObject:DummyObject):void
        {
            if (counter == 25)
            {
                for (var i:int = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    removeEventListener(DUMMY_EVENT, dummyObjects[i].listener);
                    trace("Removing", dummyObjects[i].id);
                }
            }
            trace("Handeling event", counter, dummyObject.id);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

import flash.events.Event;

class DummyObject
{
    private static var dummyObjectsCounter:int = 0;

    public var id:String;
    private var tester:TestFlashEvents;

    public function DummyObject(tester:TestFlashEvents)
    {
        this.tester = tester;
        id = "DummyObject " + dummyObjectsCounter;
        dummyObjectsCounter++;
    }

    public function listener(event:Event):void{
        tester.onGettingEvent(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now this sounds even more bug now then before. Prioritizing should not effect on when the events are removed. There is no sense in it. And about what @Vesper says, I found a way to add and remove events in O(1), so I don't think that Adobe is any worse then I am, they could do it too. This is a bug! And btw, if you try adding events while dispatching (even with prioritization), it will not work.

Comment: Prioritizing does affect the event queue. If an event has priority over another, it will be handled first in the queue, and the queue will be updated correctly, if all events have the same priority, the queue should not be updated, seeing as the 1st event isn't any more important then the last...
This is not a bug, this is architecture working as intended.

I do understand your concern, but this tbh, doing things like this can be solved in much cleaner ways...